# is uncensorship in japanese porn illegal

Tags: internet, privacy, liability, pornography, japan

According to some laws in japan censorship is a must for adult films but why does uncensored porn in JAPANESE ADULT VIDEOS ,PORNHUB,ETC exist is that legal? of not what charges they could be facing?

Comment: Because there’s money to be made - that’s why bank robbery happens too.

Comment: Are you in Japan when you see these uncensored videos?  If not, then why would they be subject to Japanese law?

Comment: No, but the people in the content are japanese (ie. AV actress from a certain company like JAV ) so even if its not in the country their adult videos are still getting exposed to the masses globally including japan itself of course (ie. pornhub jav.com etc) so why is there a uncensored videos in the first place? is it legal? or no im really confuse about their law is there a japanese person or a knowing person that could help me? thanks!

Comment: What exactly does the law require to be censored? I don't think adult movies are generally illegal in Japan, so can you please explain what kind of "censorship" you would expect?

Comment: As far as I understand the obscenity law in japan, it is about the sale of obscene material in japan...

Comment: "the people in the content are japanese": does Japanese law purport to regulate the conduct of pornographic actors based on their nationality?  Does it expose pornographic actors to prosecution based on the producer's decision to censor the film (or not to) before releasing it?

Answer (score 5):

Article 175 of the [Criminal Code](https://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/en/laws/view/3581/en) says:

> A person who distributes, sells or displays in public an obscene document, drawing or other objects shall be punished by imprisonment with work for not more than 2 years, a fine of not more than 2,500,000 yen or a petty fine. The same shall apply to a person who possesses the same for the purpose of sale.

This has been interpreted to require pixelization, blurring, censorship bars, or other means of obscuring genitalia.

See the [2013 guilty plea by publishers of Core Magazine](https://cbldf.org/2013/12/core-magazine-pleads-guilty-in-japanese-obscenity-case/) for an example prosecution under art. 175 for insufficient censorship.

The law apparently does not reach material that is produced and edited and sold outside of Japan (even if filmed in Japan). See e.g. the discussion of *Realm* (1976) in Kirsten Fischer, *The Art of Censorship in Postwar Japan*, p. 198-199:

> [the film] was not prosecutable because of Ōshima’s innovative production strategy ... He had imported the film stock from France, shot the film
> in Kyoto, and then exported the undeveloped film back to France, where
> he developed and edited it and finally distributed it internationally, including importing it back to Japan.

A "heavily cut form [was] eventually screened in Japan."